# (inverse) Fourier transform of sinc function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

$F(k)=\frac{\sin{(k+1)}}{(k+1)}$.

How can I find the inverse Fourier Transform of above function.

I am trying to use the result:
$f(t)\exp(ikt)=F(k-k_0)$.

But I am stuck.

Please help me out. I am new to Fourier transform.

Comment: A part from the shift ($+1$), have you ever encountered the Fourier transform of the box function?

Comment: Yes. But I can't figure out it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first get rid of the trivial shift, so I will consider what you call

$$ F(k-1) = \frac{\sin(k)}{k} = \mathrm{sinc}(k), $$

which is the sinc function.

The simplest way would be to recognize that the (inverse) Fourier transform of the box function is the sinc. This implies that the Fourier transform of $F(k-1)$ must be the box function. So the easiest thing would be to work backward and see what box exactly you need in order to get this particular expression for the sinc.

Let's instead work forward. We immediately face a problem as $F \notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$. This means that the integral

$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \ dk \ e^{ikx} \frac{\sin(k)}{k} $$

does not exist. What we should do is insert a cutoff $\Lambda$ after which the integral converges, and then evaluate the result as $\Lambda \to \infty$ :

$$
\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty} \int_{-\Lambda}^\Lambda dk \ e^{ikx} \frac{\sin(k)}{k}
$$

However evaluating the integral with the cut-off is cumbersome so I'll use a different approach.

We are after

$$
f(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} \ dk \ e^{ikx} \frac{e^{ik}-e^{-ik}}{2ik} $$

where the integral must actually be intended in a peculiar way. Differentiating with respect to $x$ we obtain, formally,

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \int_\mathbb{R} \ dk \ e^{ikx} \frac{e^{ik}-e^{-ik}}{2} \\
&= \pi \left ( \delta(x+1)-\delta(x-1) \right )
\end{align}

where $\delta $ is the Dirac delta. Now we know that the primitive of the Dirac delta is the Heaviside function $\theta(x)$ so, integrating with respect to $x$ we get

$$
f(x) = \pi \left ( \theta(x+1)-\theta(x-1) \right ). 
$$

This is precisely the box function between -1 and 1 and height $\pi$.

Introducing back the shift we get

$$
\hat{F}(x) = \pi \left ( \theta(x+1)-\theta(x-1) \right ) e^{-ix}
$$

Comment: Thanks for detail explaination.

Comment: @SumitSah I'm happy you appreciate it,
is everything clear? One of the ideas of this site is that if you find the answer useful you should upvote it  and/or accept it.